# Old Soviet Bike - Turist XB3 - What size pedals are these?

Tags: road-bike

I have a Turist XB3 1985 turist bike from 1985, made in Soviet Union. What size pedals are these running? I have measured the diameter and it is somewhere around 12.5 - 13mm. Could this be true that it fits 1/2" pedals?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

While the diameter of pedal axles used on Tourist may be compatible with "usual" ½ inch pedal axles, I would also double check the thread pitch of cranks/pedal threads. Searching through Russian and Ukrainian web pages gives me an impression that the bike has metric thread pitch, when modern pedals are often having thread pitch based in imperial units.

Many people had problems with rethreading the original cranks because they are made of steel, not aluminum, and tend to destroy the tap [2].

I see that some people state that French-made bikes may have compatible pedal thread pitch [1].

1. http://xt.ht/phpbb/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=35956#p473958
2. http://xt.ht/phpbb/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=308760#p1649565